# Sum of sides in a Cuboid

Tags: geometry, 3d

So, I came across this question:

> What is the value of surface area of the cuboid $C$ ?
>   (1) The length of the diagonal of $C$ is $5$
>   (2) The sum of the sides of $C$ is $10$

Now, if we take the dimensions of cuboid $C$ as $\ell, b$, and $h$, the second condition should be expressed as $4(\ell+b+h)=10$. However, the official answer expresses it simply as $\ell+b+h=10$. Doesn't a cuboid have $12$ sides(edges)?

Can someone shed some light on this.

Comment: The 'explanation' is that they probably meant the sum of the length, breadth and height of the cuboid by the sum of its sides.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri But how would one decipher such a statement during the exam?

Comment: You know now what they intend to mean when they say 'sum of sides'.

Answer (score 1):

i dont understand what do you mean by "Can someone shed some light on this."

.....Now considering the problem here

What is the surface area of the cuboid C ?

(1) The length of the diagonal of C is 5

(2) The sum of the sides of C is 10

from .....(1)

l^2+b^2+c^2=25...... draw the figure and apply pythagorous theorem

from .....(2)

- l+b+h=10 ...........OR as you thought
- 4{l+b+h}=10

### you should know this

```
                     (a + b + c)^2 = (a + x)^2 = a^2 + 2ax + x^2

                     = a^2 + 2a (b + c) + (b + c)^2 

                     = a^2 + 2ab + 2ac + (b^2 + c^2 + 2bc) 

                     = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2ab + 2bc + 2ca
```

now think a=l,b=b,c=h

now you should solve the problem......out of the two cases from {2}

IN the first case you will get a answer of 75/2

and in the second case you will get a negative value....

so you know which answer to choose